# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at useAutocomplete (useAutocomplete.js:241)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm developing react js application with material ui components.
In my application I haven't used redux.

It's everything working fine. But when I try to implement material ui autocomplete, it's not working in webpack. It's throwing this error

This is the sample code which I try to add to my application. https://codesandbox.io/s/test-material-ui-autocomplete-o3uic

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at useAutocomplete (useAutocomplete.js:241)
    at Autocomplete (Autocomplete.js:382)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:2876)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:3032)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:3453)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:124)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:144)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:159)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:4397)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:4195)
```

These are the packages I installed in my application

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.8",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.45",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "downshift": "^4.0.4",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-icons-react": "^1.0.4",
    "mui-datatables": "^2.0.0",
    "notistack": "^0.9.7",
    "npm": "^6.13.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
    "react-countdown-circle-timer": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-excel-workbook": "0.0.4",
    "react-html-table-to-excel": "^2.0.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.2.12",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.5",
    "react-material-ui-form-validator": "^2.0.9",
    "react-responsive": "^8.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.21.2",
    "react-xlsx-workbook-dynamic-column-width": "0.0.2",
    "reactstrap": "^8.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  },
```

Kindly please help me in this.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the error in your demo but I can't, what do I need to do exactly?

Comment: @bernardo, It's only throwing the error when I'm using this in webpack and babel

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this exact error myself. `@material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.45` has a peer dependency of `@material-ui/core@^4.9.0`, and they apparently really seem to mean it.  You appear locked at `@material-ui/core@^4.8.3`, and I would suggest upgrading:

```
yarn upgrade @material-ui/core@^4.9.0
```

See the exact `package.json` [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/b9dec2780203e37148d87788f727c668d9019581/packages/material-ui-lab/package.json#L37).